# Dynamically-Allocated Array Only Storing First of Multiple User-Generated Values

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

this is my first time posting here. I'm working on a lab for my CS II class (it's already past due, so I won't get any points for it at this point, but I'd still really like to understand what I'm doing wrong so that I can improve. The code is nowhere near complete, but I've hit a hangup that's keeping me from proceeding. Apologies in advance, I'm very rusty at this, and before I was rusty, I was very new. Also, I was up 'til about 4 in the morning trying to get this to work last night, so my code is probably pretty gnarly-looking at the moment.

Okay, so my issue is this: while single-stepping the code, the first function, `getNoMonths`, runs perfectly fine. It prompts the user for the number of months of sales they'd like to process the data for, and stores the number in `no_Months` back in `main`. The validation for the value needing to be between 3 and 6 also works fine.

When we get to `getSales`, the problem arises. The function prompts for the sales values of however many months the user defined earlier. It seems like it works perfectly. Upon closer inspection, however, it seems that only the first value is actually being stored in `sales`, which is supposed to be an array, the size of which is dynamically allocated according to how many months the user defined during `getNoMonths`.

I'm sure that whatever I'm doing wrong is incredibly simple, I can feel it. I've been flipping through the text again, trying to learn as much as I can about how arrays and dynamic memory allocation and pointers all work. I get the ideas behind them, but as you can probably see, I'm really struggling with the actual implementation.

I know that what I NEED to do here is:

- set up an array to hold sales data for each month
- have the size of that array match the number of months as input by the user

...I'm just not sure how to actually do it. I also know I need to have a pointer in order for the second bullet item to happen, but again, I'm not really clear on what exactly I need to do.

**TL;DR I need some help getting this `sales` array to hold ALL the values input by the user, not just the first one. To do this, I'll probably need help with setting up a pointer to dynamically allocate the size of the `sales` array, and preferably an explanation on how the hell all this actually helps me and isn't just confusing and redundant, lol.**

Source code follows:

```
//Jesse Holland
//Lab1Out
//Processes Sales Data, Displays as a Bar Graph presentation

#include <iostream>
#include "graph1.h"

using namespace std;

//FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
int getNoMonths(int& no_months);    //prompts for number of months of sales data to be processed
void getSales(int* sales, int no_months);   //prompts for sales data, stores corresponding data in "sales"
int getMax(int* sales, int no_months, double & max);    //maximum value for "sales" array
int getMin(int* sales, int no_months, double & min);    //minimum value for "sales" array
double getAvg(int* sales, int no_months, double & avg); //computes avg of sales data stored in "sales" array
void displayResults(int* sales, int no_months, int max, int min, double avg);   //displays bar chart diagram

//MAIN FUNCTION START
int main()
{
    double max = 0;
    double min = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    int no_months = 0;

    //prompt for number of months
    getNoMonths(no_months);

    //variable declaration
    int * sales = new int[no_months];

    //prompt for sales data
    getSales(sales, no_months);

    //maximum value of "sales" array
    getMax(sales, no_months, max);

    //minimum value for "sales" array
    getMin(sales, no_months, min);

    //computes avg of sales data stored in "sales" array
    getAvg(sales, no_months, avg);

    //displays bar chart diagram in graphics window
    displayResults(sales, no_months, max, min, avg);

    return 0;
}

//FUNCTIONS IMPLEMENTATION START
int getNoMonths(int& no_months) // int* months) 
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter the number of months you'd like to process: <must be at least 3, but no more than 6>:";
        cin >> no_months;
        //int* months = new int[no_months];
    }while ((no_months < 3) || (no_months > 6));

    return no_months;
}

void getSales(int* sales, int no_months)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (count = 0; count < no_months; count++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter sales for month #" << (count + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> sales[count];
    }
}

int getMax(int* sales, int no_months, double & max)
{
    //int max = 0;

    for(int count = 0; count < no_months, count++;)
    {
        if (sales[count] > max)
            max = sales[count];
    }

    return max;
}

int getMin(int* sales, int no_months, double & min)
{
    //int min = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (count = 0; count < no_months; count++)
    {
        if (sales[count] < min)
            min = sales[count];
    }

    return min;
}

double getAvg(int* sales, int no_months, double & avg)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(int count = 0; count < no_months; count++)
        sum += sales[count];

    return avg = (sum/no_months);
}

void displayResults(int* sales, int no_months, int max, int min, double avg)
{
    cout << "The maximum is " << max << ". \n";
    cout << "The minimum is " << min << ". \n";
    cout << "The average is " << avg << ". \n";
}
```

Thanks very, very much in advance for any and all help. I'm very, very green at all this, and although I'm trying very hard to get it, it seems impossible. I'm determined to learn how all this works and to be able to UNDERSTAND it so I can replicate it myself, but right now I need a little help getting there. It's hard not having any friends that no anything about this stuff and a professor who isn't terribly interested in sitting down with me and helping me work it out, either. Anyway, I look forward to hearing from you guys and hopefully learning some stuff. Maybe one day I can learn enough to be able to return the favor to newer people than I.

UPDATE: Updated source code; average is being properly calculated and output now, but still can't get max and min to do the same. Thanks for the help thus far, any further input will of course be appreciated.

Comment: There are two ways to retrieve a value from a function. Return it or output it through a reference (or pointer) parameter. In general, don't do both at the same time. Pick one. getMax should not rely on the value of a max parameter happening to be set correctly. max should be a local variable set to 0. Your average function does not update the avg parameter by reference, but you rely on this to output the result. If you don't cast either sum or no_months to a floating-point type, only integer division is performed.

Comment: @NeilKirk Thanks for the input. Quick question, by "local variable", do you mean that I need to put "int max = 0;" INSIDE the getMax function, and NOT inside of main?

Comment: @NeilKirk Also, how can I update the avg parameter by reference, as you mentioned? Would I need to changr the “double avg" in the function prototype and definition to "double & avg"? Finally, could you elaborate a little more on the last bit of what you said? Again, thanks for your input, and sorry for all the noob questions.

Comment: With the exception of C-style arrays, for a parameter of form `T x`, any changes to x inside the function do not affect the variable passed to the function. For parameters of the form `T & x`, any changes to x will modify the variable passed to the function. So `double& avg` will update the double variable passed to the function.

Comment: For the getMax function, remove the max parameter and make it a local variable set to 0. Update your call of getMax to `int max = getMax(sales, no_months);` If you want to keep it as a reference parameter, put `max = 0` at the start of the function. To see why this is necessary, try calling it twice in a row on different sets of data with the same external max variable.

Comment: http://ideone.com/9UB8vG

Comment: @NeilKirk I've never seen any of that static_cast stuff before, but thanks very much for the link--I had no idea that there were two separate formats for dividing integers and doubles/floats!

Comment: @NeilKirk in reference to making 'max' a local variable and eliminating it from 'main()', though, my question is how I'm supposed to use it again later when I want to display the max, min and average in the 'displayResults' function at the very end? If 'max' only exists in the 'getMax' function, how will 'displayResults' be able to go and look it up in order to grab it (as well as min and avg) for the 'cout' statement? I guess I'm not fully grasping why it's not good enough to pass it by reference so that it's value is changed in main, and then displayResults can reference main for the value.

Comment: It's fine to take it by reference, but your function can't assume the initial value is set to 0. If you return it, then you still have a max variable in main. See my previous code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem seems to be
`int no_months = 0;` followed by `int * sales = new int [no_months];` which basically allocates an array of size 0. Try calling `getNoMonths` before allocating the array and fix return types.

Comment: What did you mean by “fix return types"?